# AFNetworking with UIWebView issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking, uiwebviewdelegate, nsprogress

When I worked with AFNetworking before I used this method

```
webviewMain.loadRequest(request, MIMEType: mimeType, textEncodingName: textEncoding, progress: { [weak self] (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) -> Void in

        let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        self?.progressView.progress = progress

                    }, success: { (responce, data) -> NSData? in
                        return data
                    }) { [weak self] (error) -> Void in

                }
```

But now I see compilation error `Cannot convert value of type '(_, _, _) -> Void' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>' (aka 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<NSProgress>>')`

So as far as I understand I need to replace progress block with NSPredicate variable. If so I don't understand how I can track the progress.

What do I need to change?